# GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() returns empty familyname and given name

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to create a signup for user through their google account. When trying to access their details with following code:

```
 var loginInfo = new ExternalLoginInfo();
 loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

It returns empty fullname and givenname under claims. It does return emailid though. Any ideas?

Comment: What library are you using? Can you add some library or language-specific tags so experts in that area will see your question?

Answer (score 0):

Mate, this issue is because you testing Google account hasn't enable/join the Google Plus, if you have, it returns family name and given name for you, happy coding!